# all of the cells in section view are not being returned

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, spacing

I have my tableview hooked up property to my viewcontroller class however I am unable to get all of my cells to return within the sections. I want 10pix margins between each cell and was able to do this successfully in another VC, however now the method that I am using is only returning one cell (there are only 2 cells total) so I would like help in figuring out a way to display all cells within the section, code is included below:

```
  //UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()

    headerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    headerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithHex("A171FF")

    let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width:
        tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
    headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans", size: 15)
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.text = self.tableView(self.myWldTbl, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()
    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

    return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return sections[section]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch (section) {
    case 0 :
    return userMoves.count
    case 1:
    return rsvps.count
    default :
    print("unable to set up sections")
    return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row % 2 != 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MyWorldTableViewCell.self)) as! MyWorldTableViewCell

       //cell appearance
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        cell.clipsToBounds = true

       //cell data
    let evt = userMoves[indexPath.row]
    cell.rsvpCount.text = "\(rsvps.count)"

    //evt img
    if let evtImg = evt.event_photo_url {
        cell.img.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: Constants.Server.PHOTO_URL + evtImg))
    } else {
        cell.img.image = UIImage(named: "user_icon")
    }
    cell.ttl.text = evt.event_name!

    return cell } else  {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: InvisibleCell.self)) as! InvisibleCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        return cell
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        return 10.0
    }

    return 102.0
}

//UITableViewDelegate


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}
```

Comment: I tried making this calculation but I received an error when I was building the custom cells stating that the index was out of range in the switch statement it was userMoves.count * 2 to try and include the invisible rows as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

The first thing that is confusing about your code is that you appear to have 2 sections showing the contents of 2 different arrays (per the logic in `numberOfRowsInSection`), but you don't check the section number in `cellForRowAt`.

Before anything else, you should be checking `indexPath.section` in `cellForRowAt` to make sure you are using the correct array. As written, your code is using the `userMoves` array to populate both sections.

The cause of your missing cells is that you must account for the invisible separator cells in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method. You had the right idea to multiply by 2:

```
switch (section) {
    case 0 :
        return userMoves.count * 2
    //etc
}
```

When accessing the array, in `cellForRowAt`, you need to divide by 2 to avoid the index out of bounds exception:

```
if indexPath.row % 2 != 0 {
    //dequeue, etc.

    let evt = userMoves[indexPath.row / 2]

    //etc.
}
```

Comment: The idea is to add spacing between the rows, I do not see the impetus behind checking the section condition

Comment: My answer was incorrect. I have clarified the point I was making about checking the section condition, because that was a problem in your code. I also added what I believe to be the correct answer (tested in sample project).